# PHP Division with exponents

Tags: php, math, division, exponent

After some searching on the internet I'm yet to find the resource I need...I have, what I think, is a very simple question regarding math functions within PHP.

I'm computating an ELO function (for team rankings) and am unsure of what PHP math functions I use. Here is the math function: http://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/math/5/2/0/5209563cdf8a0d5b21ccc7c08d05c52b.png

I don't know how to formulate the math within PHP though. Any help is greatly appreciated...I'm pretty stuck. Doing basic division is not a problem, but I don't know how to slip in exponents.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$Rb = 65; // Set these values according to your data
$Ra = 50;

$Ea = 1 / (1 + pow(10, ($Rb - $Ra)/400)) // $Ea will have the result
```

Check out [PHP Math Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php) for documentation on all math functions available in php.